# DNN 6.2 Azure Restful service

Tags: rest, azure, dotnetnuke

I have an Azure Restful Webservice at present working well. I would like to add a DNN6.2 site to Azure and include my webservice to make a single webrole with both the DNN6.2 site and the webservice.

The created a new DNN6.2 Azure site using the DotNetNuke Azure Accelerator, which worked well, this created a service config and def file, uploaded them, created the webrole and uploaded a vhd file with the site on it.

My question is how do I add my service to this site, what is a way to do this, should I download the vhd and make modifications to it?

Any help appreciated, I have had a steep learning curve to get the Webservice up and running, now trying to learn DNN to get a solution that will work.

Answer (score 0):

The actual website is located on the VHD so this is a viable option indeed:

1. Download VHD
2. Mount VHD
3. Apply modifications
4. Reupload VHD

There are a few issues with this approach, like its harder to deploy automatically (but still possible), always having to download and upload the VHD can take some time (what happens with users currently visiting the site), you will need to unmount the drive after uploading the new VHD which could cause some downtime, ...

Not the perfect solution in my opinion.

I would suggest 2 other options:

1. Host an [FTP Server](http://khailiangtech.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/windows-azure-how-to-enable-ftp/) in that same WebRole and set the path to the drive. This will allow you to connect to the drive from your machine and upload the changes you are interested in without having to play around with the VHD. The changes described in the article should be applied in this file: **DNNAzureSMB\DNNAzure\WebRole.cs** (Note: it would be good to think about security and also  configure IP restrictions on the FTP server).
2. Don't use a WebRole. Simply go for the newly released feature called [Virtual Machines](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/) (IaaS). This means you can manage a persisted VM and you can simply install DNN as if you would install it on a server in your datacenter or on-premises.